# The entity type <type> is not part of the model for the current context. multiple connection string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im using 2 connection string the problem the 1st connection is working but when i add another connection string this is my error "The entity type  is not part of the model for the current context". im new bee here asp.net mvc5. im stuck here please help. Thank you

Here is my Code 2nd Context not working:

```
public class ChenvelJapanContext : DbContext
{
    public ChenvelJapanContext()
        : base("name=chenveljapanconnstring")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(type => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
            .Where(type => type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
            type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ChenvelJapanEntityTypeConfiguration<>));

        foreach(var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The First Context is working:

```
public class ChenvelIntlContext : DbContext
{
    public ChenvelIntlContext()
        : base("name=chenvelintlconnstring")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(type => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
            .Where(type => type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
            type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ChenvelIntlEntityTypeConfiguration<>));

        foreach(var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

My Connection String:

```
connectionStrings>
<add name="chenvelintlconnstring" connectionString="data source=server;initial catalog=chenvel_intl;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=secret;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="chenveljapanconnstring" connectionString="data source=server;initial catalog=chenvel;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=secret;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

App_start

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
        kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
        kernel.Bind<IUserInRoleService>().To<UserInRoleService>();
        kernel.Bind<IRoleService>().To<RoleService>();
        kernel.Bind<IClientService>().To<ClientService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICountryService>().To<CountryService>();
        kernel.Bind<IStateService>().To<StateService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICityService>().To<CityService>();
        kernel.Bind<ITownService>().To<TownService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPackageService>().To<PackageService>();
        kernel.Bind<IOrderService>().To<OrderService>();
        kernel.Bind<IRateService>().To<RateService>();
        kernel.Bind<IRateItemService>().To<RateItemService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICommissionService>().To<CommissionService>();
        kernel.Bind<IReceiverService>().To<ReceiverService>();
        kernel.Bind<IEmptyBoxService>().To<EmptyBoxService>();
        kernel.Bind<ITransactionService>().To<TransactionService>();
        kernel.Bind<IShipmentService>().To<ShipmentService>();
        kernel.Bind<IShipmentItemService>().To<ShipmentItemService>();
        kernel.Bind<IEmployeeService>().To<EmployeeService>();
        kernel.Bind<IDesignationService>().To<DesignationService>();
        kernel.Bind<IDeliveryService>().To<DeliveryService>();
        kernel.Bind<IDeliveryItemService>().To<DeliveryItemService>();
        kernel.Bind<IAdditionalChargeService>().To<AdditionalChargeService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICSI_DataService>().To<CSI_DataService>();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Pls, give us the code you bind your contexts in the Startup. And how do you resolve Contexts? Via Construction DI or ServiceLocator?

Comment: @Dmitriy sorry but im not familiar with DI and ServiceLocator and by the way i already add the appstart code please check. thanks

Comment: I see you bind services (I'm not so familiar with Ninject, prefering standard Microsoft DI, but I don't understand why do you bind it in the static method), but where is your `ChenvelIntlContext` and `ChenvelJapanContext` binding?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest checking the configurations and check on which model your calling db actions. The error itself says "The entity type  is not part of the model for the current context." or provide more code to analyse.

You will probably need to debug this part of code too.

```
foreach(var type in typesToRegister)
{
    dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
}
```

Comment: please close this topic i resolve the problem by adding another UnitOfWork the system doesnt accept same name of UnitOfWork.
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork2>().To<UnitOfWork2>();